# paste image on between border and background in html?

Tags: html, css, web

I will create page follow image but I can't.

[image]

this image is page that I created.

[image]

I coding *.css* file follow this code for orange border.

```css
> p {background-color: #ff6138;
  width: 1535px;
  height: 200px
}
```

How to make user image display half between orange border and white background?

Comment: I'm sorry that miss question and thank you for you're edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use negative `margin-top` for avatar `img` tag, something like

```
img#avatar {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

(50px value is just ballpark and you need to adjust it)

Comment: thank you. I try use style="margin:-50px" and it's work.